# Haskell: Get path from every leaf node to root in a Bin tree structure

Tags: haskell, binary-tree

I've got work to do, but i dunno how to do it.
I have Bin tree

```
    1
   /  \
  2    3
 / \  / \
4  5  6  7
```

And I need to find the way from root to Node with the coord [i, j].
For example: (2, 2) -> [1, 3, 6]

```
fromRoot :: Int -> Int -> Tree a -> [a]
```

I wrote some function for Index and BinTree, but how to make main function i dont know.

```
data Tree a = Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)

index :: Tree a -> Int -> Int -> a
index (Node _ x _ ) 0 _ = x
index (Node l x r) i j  | ((border i)<j) = index r (i-1) (j-(border i)-1)       
                        | otherwise = index l (i-1) j


border :: Int -> Int
border 0 = 0
border 1 = 0
border l = 2*(border (l-1))+1

myBuild :: Int  -> Tree Int
myBuild n = (Node (myBuild (n*2)) n (myBuild (n*2+1)))
```

Comment: What are coordinates? Why does the input `(2,2)` correspond to the output `[1,3,6]`? What are the two `Int` inputs to `index` supposed to represent?

Comment: level and number of element. (0 0) -> 1; (1 0) -> 2; (2 1) -> 5

Answer (score 2):

Since this is homework I won't give a complete solution, but some hints:

- how do you represent an empty tree with your Tree type?
- how do you represent the example tree (or any other finite tree)?

Considering the main function: you don't necessarily need one, a good way to start is running

```
ghci your_source_file.hs
```

You can then evaluate parts of your program, e.g.:

```
fromRoot 2 3 t1 -- if you have a t1 is a tree
```

Apart from that you could write a main function like this:

```
test_tree = ...   -- you need to fill in the dots (see questions above)

main :: IO ()
main = do print (fromRoot 2 2 test_tree)
```

If you need to find some documentation, use http://haskell.org/hoogle/

Comment: `test_tree = myBuild 1` it build my bin tree. I understand, that I need some recursion in `fromRoot` and some comparing, but how to write it right, I dont know :(

Comment: `test_tree` is infinite, probably not what you want.
You should derive Tree from Show: `data Tree a = Node (Tree a) a (Tree a) deriving Show`. Then you can try to evaluate `myBuild 1` in ghci (Ctrl-C will help you ;-) ).

Comment: A better term would be "derive Show for Tree".

Comment: Sorry guys, but I dont understand how it should be. Could you get me a complete solution, please.

Comment: What specific questions do you have, PePe? Did you think about the questions I gave you? Did you use ghci? Without further information it's really hard to help you.

Comment: ok, now i have a lot of `(node (node (node (node ...` And I think, I should select second node in second node for (2,2) or smth like this?

Comment: How would you represent your example tree (the one with nodes from 1 to 7) with your data structure? Hint: you will need some kind of termination if you want to have finite trees (leaves or empty trees).
If you still cannot find a suitable data structure, look for similar questions on stackoverflow.