# Haskell: Get path from every leaf node to root

Tags: haskell, tree, root

I have a simular qwestion [Haskell: Get path from every leaf node to root in a Bin tree structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077802/haskell-get-path-from-every-leaf-node-to-root-in-a-bin-tree-structure). And there no answer.

(Find way). coords (2, 2) -> [2, 1, 0]
I have tree where every level start with 0.

```
   0
  / \
 0   1
/ \ / \
0 1 2 3
........
```

I wrote some code, but it doesn't work (of cource...)

```
fromroot 0 _ _ = []
fromroot i j (Node t1 x t2)
   = if (j div (2^(i-1)))
        then x++ (fromroot (i-1) (j-2^(i-1)) t2)
        else x++ (fromroot (i-1) j t1)
```

`tree` i took from there thread.

```
data Tree a = Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)

myBuild :: Int  -> Tree Int
myBuild n = (Node (myBuild (n*2)) n (myBuild (n*2+1)))
```

Hope, you'll help me.

**UPD 1**

Input `> fromroot 3 2 (myBuild 0)`
and error on `myBuild` function.

```
    Couldn't match expected type `[a0]' with actual type `Int'
    Expected type: Tree [a0]
      Actual type: Tree Int
    In the return type of a call of `myBuild'
    In the third argument of `fromroot', namely `(myBuild 0)'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: Do you build the thee along the way, or you have a ready-made tree to traverse?

Comment: along the way. But it doesn't matter

Comment: What do you expect `j div (2^(i-1))` to do?

Comment: Btw, it helps us if you post the compiler error message (when the code doesn't compile) or a failing test case (i.e. sample input, the output you expect/desire from your function for that input, the output your function actually gives you).

Comment: `j div (2^(i-1))` should choose go to left or right. I upd 1st message.

Comment: I meant, how do you think it calculates it?

Answer (score 1):

### Hint

Let's try to get element (2,3) [Level 2, Element #3 as an explanation for the coordinates used here] out of your original tree.

```
   0
  / \
 0   1
/ \ / \
0 1 2 3
```

Now this is the same as getting element (1,1) out of the subtree (which is trivial to do!)

```
 1
/ \
2 3
```

Now think of an example for a tree with one more level. And do the recursion trick.

Answer (score 0):

You think you have written `fromroot` to take a `Tree a` as its third argument, but instead you have written it to take a `Tree [a]`.

This is because you use `x` as a list, instead of prepending it to the list returned from the recursive call.

To prepend a single element to a list, you use `:`. `++` is for concatenating two lists together.

(I also think your if condition should be `` 0 /= (j `div` (2^(i-1))) `` instead of `j div (2^(i-1))`, because (1) to use named functions as an operator they must be enclosed in backticks, and (2) `if` takes a `Bool`, and does not cast from e.g. `Int` for you. But that wasn't what the error message you posted was complaining about.)

There may be other mistakes; I haven't checked.

Comment: In `fromroot`, after the `then` and after the `else`, you have `x ++ ...`.